# Asio on Linux stalls in epoll()

Tags: linux, sockets, boost-asio

We're experiencing a problem with asynchronous operation of standalone (non-Boost) Asio 1.10.6 on Linux, which is demonstrated using the following test app:

```
#define ASIO_STANDALONE
#define ASIO_HEADER_ONLY
#define ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#define ASIO_NO_TYPEID
#include "asio.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <thread>

static bool s_freeInboundSocket = false;
static bool s_freeOutboundSocket = false;

class Tester
{
public:
    Tester(asio::io_service& i_ioService, unsigned i_n)
        : m_inboundStrand(i_ioService)
        , m_listener(i_ioService)
        , m_outboundStrand(i_ioService)
        , m_resolver(i_ioService)
        , m_n(i_n)
        , m_traceStart(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now())
    {}

    ~Tester()
    {}

    void TraceIn(unsigned i_line)
    {
        m_inboundTrace.emplace_back(i_line, std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - m_traceStart));
    }

    void AbortIn(unsigned i_line)
    {
        TraceIn(i_line);
        abort();
    }

    void TraceOut(unsigned i_line)
    {
        m_outboundTrace.emplace_back(i_line, std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - m_traceStart));
    }

    void AbortOut(unsigned i_line)
    {
        TraceOut(i_line);
        abort();
    }

    void DumpTrace(std::map<unsigned, unsigned>& o_counts)
    {
        std::cout << "## " << m_n << " ##\n";
        std::cout << "-- " << m_traceStart.time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";
        std::cout << "- in -             - out -\n";

        auto in = m_inboundTrace.begin();
        auto out = m_outboundTrace.begin();

        while ((in != m_inboundTrace.end()) || (out != m_outboundTrace.end()))
        {
            if (in == m_inboundTrace.end()) 
            {
                ++o_counts[out->first];

                std::cout << "                  " << out->first << " : " << out->second.count() << "\n";
                ++out;
            }
            else if (out == m_outboundTrace.end())  
            {
                ++o_counts[in->first];

                std::cout << in->first << " : " << in->second.count() << "\n";
                ++in;
            }
            else if (out->second < in->second)
            {
                ++o_counts[out->first];

                std::cout << "                  " << out->first << " : " << out->second.count() << "\n";
                ++out;
            }
            else
            {
                ++o_counts[in->first];

                std::cout << in->first << " : " << in->second.count() << "\n";
                ++in;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    //////////////
    // Inbound

    void Listen(uint16_t i_portBase)
    {
        m_inboundSocket.reset(new asio::ip::tcp::socket(m_inboundStrand.get_io_service()));

        asio::error_code ec;
        if (m_listener.open(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), ec)
         || m_listener.bind(asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), i_portBase+m_n), ec)
         || m_listener.listen(-1, ec))
        {
            AbortIn(__LINE__); return;
        }

        TraceIn(__LINE__);

        m_listener.async_accept(*m_inboundSocket,
            m_inboundStrand.wrap([this](const asio::error_code& i_error)
        {
            OnInboundAccepted(i_error);
        }));
    }

    void OnInboundAccepted(const asio::error_code& i_error)
    {
        TraceIn(__LINE__);

        if (i_error) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }

        asio::async_read_until(*m_inboundSocket, m_inboundRxBuf, '\n',
            m_inboundStrand.wrap([this](const asio::error_code& i_err, size_t i_nRd)
        {
            OnInboundReadCompleted(i_err, i_nRd);
        }));
    }


    void OnInboundReadCompleted(const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nRead)
    {
        TraceIn(__LINE__);

        if (i_error.value() != 0) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }
        if (bool(i_error)) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }
        if (i_nRead != 4) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }  // "msg\n"

        std::istream is(&m_inboundRxBuf);
        std::string s;
        if (!std::getline(is, s)) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }
        if (s != "msg") { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }
        if (m_inboundRxBuf.in_avail() != 0) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }

        asio::async_read_until(*m_inboundSocket, m_inboundRxBuf, '\n',
            m_inboundStrand.wrap([this](const asio::error_code& i_err, size_t i_nRd)
        {
            OnInboundWaitCompleted(i_err, i_nRd);
        }));

    }

    void OnInboundWaitCompleted(const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nRead)
    {
        TraceIn(__LINE__);

        if (i_error != asio::error::eof) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }
        if (i_nRead != 0) { AbortIn(__LINE__); return; }

        if (s_freeInboundSocket)
        {
            m_inboundSocket.reset();
        }
    }

    //////////////
    // Outbound

    void Connect(std::string i_host, uint16_t i_portBase)
    {
        asio::error_code ec;
        auto endpoint = m_resolver.resolve(asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query(i_host, std::to_string(i_portBase+m_n)), ec);
        if (ec) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; }

        m_outboundSocket.reset(new asio::ip::tcp::socket(m_outboundStrand.get_io_service()));

        TraceOut(__LINE__);

        asio::async_connect(*m_outboundSocket, endpoint,
            m_outboundStrand.wrap([this](const std::error_code& i_error, const asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator& i_ep)
        {
            OnOutboundConnected(i_error, i_ep);
        }));
    }

    void OnOutboundConnected(const asio::error_code& i_error, const asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator& i_endpoint)
    {
        TraceOut(__LINE__);

        if (i_error) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; }

        std::ostream(&m_outboundTxBuf) << "msg" << '\n';

        asio::async_write(*m_outboundSocket, m_outboundTxBuf.data(),
            m_outboundStrand.wrap([this](const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nWritten)
        {
            OnOutboundWriteCompleted(i_error, i_nWritten);
        }));
    }

    void OnOutboundWriteCompleted(const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nWritten)
    {
        TraceOut(__LINE__);

        if (i_error) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; }
        if (i_nWritten != 4) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; } // "msg\n"

        TraceOut(__LINE__);
        m_outboundSocket->shutdown(asio::socket_base::shutdown_both);

        asio::async_read_until(*m_outboundSocket, m_outboundRxBuf, '\n',
            m_outboundStrand.wrap([this](const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nRead)
        {
            OnOutboundWaitCompleted(i_error, i_nRead);
        }));
    }

    void OnOutboundWaitCompleted(const asio::error_code& i_error, size_t i_nRead)
    {
        TraceOut(__LINE__);

        if (i_error != asio::error::eof) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; }
        if (i_nRead != 0) { AbortOut(__LINE__); return; }

        if (s_freeOutboundSocket)
        {
            m_outboundSocket.reset();
        }
    }

private:
    //////////////
    // Inbound

    asio::io_service::strand m_inboundStrand;

    asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_listener;
    std::unique_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_inboundSocket;

    asio::streambuf m_inboundRxBuf;
    asio::streambuf m_inboundTxBuf;

    //////////////
    // Outbound

    asio::io_service::strand m_outboundStrand;

    asio::ip::tcp::resolver m_resolver;
    std::unique_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> m_outboundSocket;

    asio::streambuf m_outboundRxBuf;
    asio::streambuf m_outboundTxBuf;

    //////////////
    // Common

    unsigned m_n;

    const std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point m_traceStart;
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, std::chrono::nanoseconds>> m_inboundTrace;
    std::vector<std::pair<unsigned, std::chrono::nanoseconds>> m_outboundTrace;
};

static int Usage(int i_ret)
{
    std::cout << "[" << i_ret << "]" << "Usage: example <nThreads> <nConnections> <inboundFree> <outboundFree>" << std::endl;
    return i_ret;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 5)
        return Usage(__LINE__);

    const unsigned nThreads = unsigned(std::stoul(argv[1]));
    if (nThreads == 0)
        return Usage(__LINE__);
    const unsigned nConnections = unsigned(std::stoul(argv[2]));
    if (nConnections == 0)
        return Usage(__LINE__);

    s_freeInboundSocket = (*argv[3] == 'y');
    s_freeOutboundSocket = (*argv[4] == 'y');

    const uint16_t listenPortBase = 25000;
    const uint16_t connectPortBase = 25000;
    const std::string connectHost = "127.0.0.1";

    asio::io_service ioService;

    std::cout << "Creating." << std::endl;

    std::list<Tester> testers;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nConnections; ++i)
    {
        testers.emplace_back(ioService, i);
        testers.back().Listen(listenPortBase);
        testers.back().Connect(connectHost, connectPortBase);
    }

    std::cout << "Starting." << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i)
    {   
        threads.emplace_back([&]()
        {
            ioService.run();
        });
    }

    std::cout << "Waiting." << std::endl;

    for (auto& thread : threads)
    {
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Stopped." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void DumpAllTraces(std::list<Tester>& i_testers)
{
    std::map<unsigned, unsigned> counts;

    for (auto& tester : i_testers)
    {
        tester.DumpTrace(counts);
    }   

    std::cout << "##############################\n";
    for (const auto& count : counts)
    {
        std::cout << count.first << " : " << count.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

#if defined(ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS)
namespace asio
{
        namespace detail
        {

                template <typename Exception>
                void throw_exception(const Exception& e)
                {
            abort();
                }

        } // namespace detail
} // namespace asio
#endif
```

We compile as follows (the problem only occurs in optimised builds):

```
g++ -o example -m64 -g -O3 --no-exceptions --no-rtti --std=c++11 -I asio-1.10.6/include -lpthread example.cpp
```

We're running on Debian Jessie.  `uname -a` reports `(Linux <hostname> 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.
The problem appears under both GCC (`g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2`) and Clang (`Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)`).

[EDITED TO ADD:  It also happens on Debian Stretch `Linux <hostname> 4.6.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.1-1 (2016-06-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux` with `g++ (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124`.]

In summary, the test app does the following:

- We create N connections, each consisting of an inbound (listening)
  end and an outbound (connecting) end.  Each inbound listener is bound
  to a unique port (starting at 25000), and each outbound connector
  uses a system-selected originating port.
- The inbound end performs an `async_accept`, and on
  completion issues an `async_read`.  When the read completes it issues
  another async_read that we expect to return `eof`.  When that
  completes, we either free the socket immediately, or leave it as-is
  (with no pending async operations) to be cleaned up by the relevant
  destructors at program exit.  (Note that the listener socket is
  always left as-is, with no pending accept, until exit.)
- The outbound end performs an `async_connect`, and on completion issues
  an `async_write`.  When the write completes it issues a `shutdown`
  (specifically, `shutdown(both)`) followed by an `async_read` that we
  expect to return `eof`.  On completion, we once again either leave the
  socket as-is, with no pending operations, or we free it immediately.
- Any error or unexpected receive data results in an immediate `abort()`
  call.
- The test app lets us specify the number of worker threads for the
  `io_service`, as well as the total number of connections to create, as
  well as flags controlling whether inbound and outbound sockets
  respectively are freed or left as-is.
- We run the test app repeatedly, specifying 50 threads and 1000
  connections.

  i.e. `while ./example 50 1000 n y >out.txt ; do echo -n . ; done`

If we specify that all sockets are left as-is, the test loop runs indefinitely.  To avoid muddying the waters with `SO_REUSEADDR` considerations, we take care that no sockets are in `TIME_WAIT` state from a previous test run before we start the test, otherwise the listens can fail.  But with this caveat satisfied, the test app runs literally hundreds, even thousands of times with no error.  Similarly, if we specify that inbound sockets (but NOT outbound sockets) should be explicitly freed, all runs fine.

However, if we specify that outbound sockets should be freed, the app stalls after a variable number of executions - sometimes ten or fewer, sometimes a hundred or more, usually somewhere in between.

Connecting to the stalled process with GDB, we see that the main thread is waiting to join the worker threads, all but one of the worker threads are idle (waiting on an Asio internal condition variable), and that one worker thread is waiting in Asio's call to `epoll()`.  The internal trace instrumentation verifies that some of the sockets are waiting on async operations to complete - sometimes the initial (inbound) accept, sometimes the (inbound) data read, and sometimes the final inbound or outbound reads that normally complete with `eof`.

In all cases, the other end of the connection has successfully done its bit: if the inbound accept is still pending, we see that the corresponding outbound connect has successfully completed, along with the outbound write;  likewise if the inbound data read is pending, the corresponding outbound connect and write have completed; if the inbound EOF read is pending, the outbound shutdown has been performed, and likewise if the outbound EOF read is pending, the inbound EOF read has completed due to the outbound shutdown.

Examining the process's /proc/N/fdinfo shows that the epoll file descriptor is indeed waiting on the file descriptors indicated by the instrumentation.

Most puzzlingly, `netstat` shows nonzero RecvQ sizes for the waiting sockets - that is, sockets for which there is a read operation pending are shown to have receive data or close events ready to read.  This is consistent with our instrumentation, in that it shows that write data has been delivered to the inbound socket, but has not yet been read (or alternatively that the outbound shutdown has issued a FIN to the inbound side, but that the EOF has not yet been 'read').

This leads me to suspect that Asio's `epoll` bookkeeping - in particular its edge-triggered event management - is getting out of sync somewhere due to a race condition.  Clearly this is more than likely due to incorrect operations on my part, but I can't see where the problem would be.

All insights, suggestions, known issues, and pointing-out-glaring-screwups would be greatly appreciated.

[EDITED TO ADD:  Using `strace` to capture kernel calls interferes with execution such that the stall doesn't happen.  Using `sysdig` doesn't have this effect, but it currently doesn't capture the parameters of the `epoll_wait` and `epoll_ctl` syscalls. Sigh.]

Comment: check your ephemeral port range. You  might need to increase it.

Comment: Have you tested with an earlier release of asio? Or perhaps a newer? At Github they have two newer releases, asio-1-10-7 and asio-1-10-8, and if I'm not mistaken there were some changes to the epoll reactor in those releases.

Comment: @gurka - All versions 1.10.0 to 1.10.8 exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: @Arunmu - It's definitely worth investigating, but in the meantime I've confirmed for what it's worth that src-dst port combinations are never repeated in the failing tests.

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, that makes the behaviour correct, but the way you have mentioned about the process getting stuck sounds very familiar. It's usually related to OS waiting to get new/free port from the current ephemeral range.

Comment: @Arunmu - Good to know, will investigate.  But as I understand it, ephemeral port exhaustion principally affects multiple outbound connections to the _same_ destination address/port, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been resolved by the maintainer of ASIO:

See https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/180

and https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/commit/669e6b8b9de1309927b29d8b6be3630cc69c07ac